# How to compare string in if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, strcpy

I am a beginner in C++ and I was trying to make a decision function which I could use in future programs.

The idea is that the program would ask a yes/no question, the user would type in `yes` or `no` and they would receive an output according to their answer. But when I try running the code, the program shows the output for the `"yes"` case no matter what the answer. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class dec
{
    public:
        int flag;
        char yn[3];

        void decision()
        {
            std::cout<<"Enter yes or no:\n";
            std::cin>>yn;
            flag=0;
            while(flag==0)
            {
                if(strcpy(yn,"yes"))
                    flag=1;
                else if(strcpy(yn,"no"))
                    flag=-1;
                else
                {
                    std::cout<<"Invalid input.\n";
                    flag=0;
                }
            }
        }
        void reset()
        {
            flag=0;
        }
};

main()
{
    dec d;
    std::cout<<"Test?\n";
    d.decision();
    if(d.flag==1)
        std::cout<<"Correct.";
    else
        std::cout<<"Wrong.";
}
```

No matter what I type, the output is always `"Correct"`. Please help.

PS: I'm using `flag` so that I can reuse the function again when needed.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char[]`, then you can use `yn == "yes"` for example. In any case, [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is what you use for string comparison, not [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) which does a copy.

Comment: @CoryKramer: That's pretty much the answer - can you make it a real answer so we can mark this question answered?

Comment: `std::cin>>yn;` -- Your code now has one of the most exploited vulnerabilities -- buffer overrun.  What happens if I type in 100 characters instead of 2?  Classes such as `std::string` prevent these things from happening.

Comment: Unrelated: Thumbs up for not `using namespace std;`!

Comment: You should only need to compare once, if you convert to all lower case or all upper case before the compare.  Search the internet for "c++ transform string toupper".

Comment: @CoryKramer where do I use ```std::string``` in the code? ```std::cin>>std::string yn```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcpy()` **copies** a string into a character array. Instead you need to use  `strcmp()` to **compare** two arrays. You do it like this:

```
if (strcmp(yn, "yes") == 0)
```

Also beware that you need to declare `char yn[4]` to allow for a terminating NULL character.

Alternatively, you can use `std::string` instead of an array and then compare strings with `==`:

```
if (yn == "yes")
```

Comment: Don't know why the strcmp() suggestion did not work. Stil shows the answer as "Correct." The ```std::string``` suggestion worked though. Anyway, thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ArunRavindranath Make sure you declare `char yn[4];`. Notice that you have declare an array with **four** elements, not three. Also use the syntax I show above when using `strcmp()`. For details, you should read the documentation for this function. If your code still isn't quite right, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code to see what's going on.

Comment: @ArunRavindranath On a side note: what happens when the user types in "abcd" or something else other than "yes" or "no"?

Comment: if user types in something other than "yes" or "no" ```flag=0``` and the while loop repeats again until the answer is yes or no. BTW, thanks for the advice. I didn't use "==0" in strcmp() before, which is why it showed "Correct." Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @ArunRavindranath That is only what you think the code does. You should actually try it. Hint: how will the answer change after the first time the user enters one?